# Auto-select the correct subclass to instantiate from keywords in Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, instantiation

There are some subclasses, which inherit from one baseclass. Now I would like the program to automatically choose the correct subclass and instantiate it, according to the input from a list.

What is the best way to do this? I know there is the possibility to make a factory method with an if-elif statement. But I'd rather like the subclasses to register themselves to the baseclass, to make the system as modular as possible. So that, when a new subclass is added, everything else can stay unchanged.

I read about factory classes, factory methods, metaclasses and decorators. But in the end I would like to have some kind of create(subclass_keyword) method in the baseclass. This method gets a keyword as input, selects the correct subclass to instantiate and returns it. Is this possible in Python 3.x?

I tried to do it, but didn't succeed yet. Do you have some hints on how to tackle the challenge? Here is the code to demonstrate my goal:

```
class Shape:
    subclasses = dict()
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    @staticmethod
    def register_subclass(subclass, name):
        Shape.subclasses[name] = subclass
        return subclass
    @staticmethod
    def create(shape_type, width, height):
        return Shape.subclasses[shape_type](width, height)

@Shape.register_subclass('circle')
class Circle(Shape):
    def draw(self): print("Draw circle of %s x %s." % (str(self.width), str(self.height)))
    def erase(self): print ("Erase circle.")

@Shape.register_subclass('square')
class Square(Shape):
    def draw(self): print("Draw square of %s x %s." % (str(self.width), str(self.height)))
    def erase(self): print ("Erase square")

forms_str = ["square", "circle", "circle", "square"]
forms = []
for item in forms_str:
    forms.append(Shape.create(item, 10, 10))

for elem in forms:
    elem.draw()
    elem.erase()
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: It seems that the only thing that doesn't work is your `@Shape.register_subclass('circle')` decorator. Maybe you should just ask how to implement decorators correctly?

Comment: Well, since I didn't use decorators before, I don't know how to use the `register_subclass()` method correctly. Right now this function needs two arguments, but I don't know what to enter as input for the parameter `subclass`. So it's giving me the `NameError: name 'Circle' is not defined`.

Comment: @BrandonBarney I don't think that the answer of the other article really answers my question. I want to be able to choose between subclasses, not be able to add certain attributes.